# Delphi command-line compiler

Tags: delphi, command-line, compiler-construction

I have a project with a few apps with a couple of {$DEF aaaaa}  and then I use Inno setup to do a installer.
To streamline the process it would be great to create a batch file to do the whole thing from A to Z.
Hence the need to use the line compiler I never did that in 10+ years of delphi.

Given that the help is... well we all know about the help

Where can I find some documentation/tutorial on this topic if would be nice if the IDE would produce a file with all the parameters to be used with the line compiler may be it does (it does internally but...)  then where??
Should I use Msbuild or DCC32.exe and some file ??? if MSbuild how do you use the stuff

I have no clue where to start any hint in the right direction wold be appreciated

Thank you
PW

Comment: See the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990400/how-can-i-perform-a-dry-run-of-msbuild-for-a-delphi-project for a way to capture DCC32 command line parameters

Answer (score 3):

See here: http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Compile_from_Commandline

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Delphi version that supports MSBuild directly it is easier to use it because it can read most parameters from your Delphi and project settings, while DCC32 requires a little more work to use it.
There are also many tools to automate a build (both free/open source or commercial), but for simple needs even a batch file could be enough.

Comment: Example for D2007: http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Compile_from_Commandline Unfortunately I could not find anyone for D2010.

Comment: I wrote that article and if I remember correctly it is still the same procedure for Delphi 2010 as it was for Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 1):

A good start:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DCC32.EXE,_the_Delphi_Command_Line_Compiler
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_compiler_directives

The big picture:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Command_Line_Utilities_Index

Answer (score 0):

DCC32 does output its own help if called in either of these ways:

```
dcc32
dcc32 -h
dcc32 -help
```

This can be found [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DCC32.EXE,_the_Delphi_Command_Line_Compiler), as Andreas pointed out.

In Rad Studio XE (Delphi 2011), FinalBuilder will be integrated into the IDE helping with exactly this. i would therefore have a look into the [product](http://www.finalbuilder.com/home.aspx), as you would prepare for the future using it.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you mention msbuild can we assume you have a reasonably recent version of Delphi? As mentioned already [FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com) is great for this sort of thing. there is a FinalBuilder action for doing this which basically boils down to a command line of:

```
msbuild /target:Build /property:config=Release;UsePackages=false myapp.dproj
```

Change the config= as approriate and add/remove other property: settings as you choose.
Compiling using dcc32 is fine and still perfectly doable but msbuild is definitely a bit more straightforward now as it is much easier to build different configurations.

```
msbuild -h
```

is a good starting point as are all the links already given.