# How are Delphi 'environment variables' such as $(BDS) evaluated?

Tags: delphi, path, environment-variables

I'm making some tidy installers for our internal libraries (instead of just opening the DPK's and clicking 'install' and getting in a mess later...) and this has caused me to have to understand how to get at various Delphi variables such as [Known Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813024/how-to-install-a-delphi-component-package-from-the-command-line), the registry RootDir value etc.

I see that within Delphi there are a number of variables that you can use (within a search path for example) such as $(BDS) etc. When I look into my machine environment variables I dont see these, either in system or current user.

My questions are:

1. Is Delphi doing something internal to expand $(BDS) etc itself? Or can I use these externally in some way (eg looked up in the registry).
2. Why is the notation $(xxxx) within a search path and not %xxxx% as with an envirnment variable?
   Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1) They are simply environment variables which Delphi sets for its own process and you can retrieve them with [GetEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from a design package installed in the IDE; here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970994/is-there-a-delphi-library-which-returns-all-effective-source-paths-for-a-project/972465#972465).

If your installer is a separate executable, you can still (more or less reliably) guess where to get some of the values:

- `BDS`: `RootDir` value in the registry, e.g. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\`
- `BDSCOMMONDIR`: in older versions (Delphi 2007, I guess) this was a global environment variable, set by the Delphi installer. In later versions you can find it in `rsvars.bat`.

Some others might probably be derived, e.g.:

- `BDSLIB`: `$(BDS)\lib`
- `BDSINCLUDE`: `$(BDS)\include`

User-defined variables (defined in Delphi's Environment Options dialog) are stored in the `Environment Variables` registry subkey.

2) The `$(...)` notation is IMHO simply better because it has distinct opening and closing delimiters, it's easier to work with for search/replace operations and also more readable.

Comment: Pity though that they are only available from within the IDE (spawned?) processes... Still looking for the default values, but my suspicion is that they may simply be hardcoded into the BDS and the DCC32 executables... :(

Comment: @Marjan: Why would they be available anywhere else?  They're probably generated relative to the running BDS.exe, and meaningless outside the process, since you can have multiple BDS installs.  The best persistent place you're likely to find would be the uninstall registrations.

Comment: @Craig: because they are useful in many more situations than just the IDE. It would be nice if they could be re-used in a build server. Now you have to duplicate these kinds of settings in there as well.

Comment: rsvars.bat will install all the vars in your shell.

Answer (score 7):

I'm working on a bit of command line build automation (because I want to move away from Final Builder) so I had to deal with those special variables. To invoke the command-line compiler we're supposed to either invoke the command prompt using the "RAD Studio Command Prompt" from the Start menu, or to include the "rsvars.bat" script into our own scripts.

That rsvars.bat script looks like this:

```
@SET BDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0
@SET BDSCOMMONDIR=C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0
@SET FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
@SET FrameworkVersion=v2.0.50727
@SET FrameworkSDKDir=
@SET PATH=%FrameworkDir%;%FrameworkSDKDir%;%PATH%
@SET LANGDIR=EN
```

As you can notice, the very special BDS variable is set in there, as well as some others. The BDS path corresponds with the BDS installation path in the Registry, but I decided to read it from the `rsvars.bat` script, hoping it'll be more future-proof. So I'm essentially reading the `.bat` file into a `TStringList` and I'm applying a simple RegEx to identify the assignments.

My routine that expands those `$(Nam)` style expressions includes a special case for the `DELPHI` name, to handle Delphi7: If I see that, I replace it with the installation path of the IDE.

Comment: Intereting, thanks. "I'm working on a bit of command line build automation (because I want to move away from Final Builder)" - wot you doing, wot you doing!!!!!! Sounds interesting.

Comment: I have tried to build my own little builder too at various points.  I recommend just moving to Delphi 2007 or later, and using MSbuild. It's pretty decent.

Comment: @Warren: Yes, I've found "CodeGear.Delphi.Targets" too in the bin folder which several users have modified.

Comment: @Warren, I need to support Delphi 7, 2010 and XE, and I'm aiming for something closer to Final Builder functionality (ie: everything from the actual Delphi build to uploading the finished installation KIT to our "beta" file server). I've been using Final Builder for a looong time, but I always end up writing tiny console applications for all sorts of special functionality and then calling those from the FB script. This  time I'm aiming at automating my scripts using dwscript (Delphi Web Script), I've got the actual Delphi builds going, putting the rest together is just a matter of time.

Answer (score 6):

The $() notation for variables is a convention used by MAKE, what Borland used as build tool before switching to MSBuild.  (in D2007?)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was really surprised what people talk about "build servers" here, but have no idea about `make`. Little correction: syntax was not invented by broland, but was common even before broland.

Comment: sure, pmake and gmake use it too. IIRC some shells (tcsh?) too.

Comment: @PrematureOptimization +1 for the Broland typo ;)

Answer (score 2):

David is right that these variables are specific to Delphi (and C++ Builder), and they are not available as "normal" environment variables.

However, they can be looked up in the registry. The key is: `HKCU\Software\<Borcadero>\BDS\<version>\Environment Variables`.

Any custom "environment" variables that you add can be found here as well. For example I have a $(MVC) variable to point to the folder where all my components(' versions) can be found.

At work we use the registry to look up the values in a script/app combination to convert dprojs to cfg files for our build server which uses the command line compiler. (As we don't use the IDE on the build machine, we have added our custom Delphi environment variables to the registry manually).

*Update*

Actually, the Environment Variables key is used for user defined environment variables and for overrides of the "standard" BDS environment variables. The default values of any $(BDS*) environment variable is nowhere to be found in the registry...

So, current knowledge says, if you want to get your hands on the values for the $(BDS*) vars, you would have to override the default values and read the ones you specified from the Environment Variables key.

Comment: AFAIK, the `Environment Variables` subkey is for user-defined variables. For Delphi XE, I don't see `BDSLIB` defined anywhere in the registry. Neither in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` nor `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

Comment: @TOndrej: you are right, though overrides of the default values for $(BDS*)'s can be found there as well, so you should always look there. The value for $(BDS) is found in: `HKCU\Software\<Borcadero>\BDS\<version>\RootDir`. Looking for the others...

Comment: Negative. David is not right and those are simply enviroment variables, set by process and (naturally) inherited by children.

Comment: @Downvoter: yes they are environment variables, set by the IDE and as such only accessible to the IDE or processes started by the IDE. They are not "simply environment variables" as they are not available outside of the IDE process tree. So David is/was(?) perfectly right in saying that they are specific to Delphi even if Delphi chose to use environment variables to implement them.

Comment: @Marjan Venema, no, they are simple and not magic at all, you just have severe misconception about environment variables. Create a seperate question and/or exercise viewing enviroment block of IDE process.

Comment: @Downvoter: What part of *outside the IDE* did you not hear? I know perfectly well that they are simple environment variables available for any dll / bpl loaded in the IDE or any process started from the IDE. I said as much. However, they are **NOT** available outside the IDE ! Try starting the IDE and opening a command window from the Windows' start button and run a `set` command. You won't see any of those environment variables there... To me that is called process, and in this case Delphi, specific.

Comment: @Marjan Venema, please familiarize yourself with environment variables *before* arguing, loose terminology is not an excuse. Variables in question are set like every variable else, only point where they being set (alt: from where being inherited) differs.

Comment: @Downvoter: please familiarize yourself with the use of quotation marks surrounding a term...

Comment: @Downvoter: you have just confirmed what I already suspected about you... :-)

Comment: @Marjan Venema, finally you figured out what resorting to "NO U" brings up ultimate victory in any argument? Good for you. My proposal to share the knowlegde why "inside" enviroment variables are not different that "outside" ones in the form of answer still stands, however. No trolling or inversion replies, please.

Comment: @Downvoter: Oh, no worries, that's not in my nature. The meaning of "NO U!" is not what you confirmed though... Please take this the way it is intended: good natured. What you confirmed for me was your apparent need for everybody to show the same kind of preciseness you demonstrate. It reminded me of me some 10-15 years back. Nowadays I am a teensy bit more lenient... :-)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, I thought I would add that when I created a new environment variable - (to be used in my DCC_UnitSearchPath as $(VISEMS) ), I observed that it was placed into the registry.

For a specific example I found it in:
  Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\Environment Variable

The "accepted answer" above needs to be updated to reflect the there are version numbers in the registry path, since in my case, the "accepted answer" is incorrect (when it says: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\ )
as there is nothing at "BDS\8.0" since 8.0 is not installed on my computer.

Comment: This information is contained in the accepted answer to the question, posted nearly 9 years ago, in the next to last paragraph. It's also in Marjan's answer (immediately above this one).

Comment: You **assume** that I was the one that downvoted - I was not. I politely pointed out that your answer duplicated what had already been posted, which it still does.