# TurboPower LockBox: how to install

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have download this component and trying to install but,
It is asking too many questions for the installation to continue :(

How do you answer to these,
BPL/DLL output directory?
Include (.inc) directories?

Delphi XE DCU output directory?
Delphi XE DCP output directory?
Delphi XE EXE output directory?

Is there any quides available for installing the component?

thanks in advance

Comment: Could I have more details on the versions your Delphi and TP LockBox ?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the LockBox installation cannot read this information from Delphi. You can find the settings in Tools->Options.

The path settings are under Environment Options->Delphi Options->Library.
There you find 
- Package output directory (= BPL/DLL output path) 
  BPLs are special DLLs (packages) that are installed in the IDE. They contain the components.
- DCP output directory (DCPs are used with BPLs when they are installed in the IDE).

You can also choose your own directories, as long as the directory is specified in the system PATH environment variable.

The .inc-directory can be left empty in the installation.

The DCU output directory is for saving the DCUs (compiled units) of the package. You can choose this directory yourself. DCP path, I explained above.

I'm not sure about EXE output directory, but maybe it is used to compile the demo applications too.

It is indeed a little vague to say the least. At the end of the installation, you'll find a link to a feedback forum. Maybe you can share your findings there, so they may improve it in the next version.

Comment: Good answer. Only the BPL directory needs to be on the path. Yes, the EXE directory is for the demo programs. In relation to directories, tThe choices are similar to those offered by the Jedi JVCL installer.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple.
You can just leave all these fields empty, and the defaults will be picked up.
Alternatively you can just deselect the automatic compile option. The installer will then just install the source code, and then you can compile and install by hand. There is a read-me file providing guidance for just that.

Comment: When I leave those fields empty, I receive [this snag message](https://www.dropbox.com/s/agv66i1f9bax7g2/Lockbox%20Installation.png)

Answer (score -1):

I advice you to kindly ask someone proficient in **InnoSetup** to pack it for you. Unfortunately, I do not have a good command of if but I know it works.

**Last edit** :

As of version 3.4.1 released on 12-Nov-2011, TurboPower Lockbox was distributed as a good binary but still requires some fair knowledge of package installing.

Please see [TOndej's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11480/tondrej) answer to [How are Delphi 'environment variables' such as $(BDS) evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870282/how-are-delphi-environment-variables-such-as-bds-evaluated) for indepth details.

Packing into an alternative binary distribution adressing the expansion of Delphi IDE environnement variables ($(BDS) and the like) may save users from troubles by hiding some complexities.

Comment: What does this have to do with installing third-party components? The author has the responsibility for creating the installer, not the person trying to install it.

Comment: @Ken White : Good idea ! But how to enforce that in an open source project ? Some authors may also be like me regarding writing setup script or leave the task to the end users. Recently, I asked a friend of mine to pack the Zeos source code package distibution to avoid the quirks of installation.

Comment: Email the person administering the OS project? Create it yourself and contribute it? Both great ideas, but it doesn't answer the question asked - sorry, but in my opinion "find someone else to do it for you" is not an answer.

Comment: @Ken White : Ok, It doesn't answer the question the productive way. I'll get down to learn Innosetup for my own sake and will try to cook a script (with my friend's assistance for the time beeing) to bring about a valuable answer.