# Where does Delphi store the values of its environment variables?

Tags: delphi, delphi-ide

Delphi uses several environment variables with a name that starts with BDS which are displayed under Tools/Options/"Environment Variables". There are so called "System variables" which include the environment variables from Windows (ALLUSERSPROFILE, APPDATA, PATH etc.) but also some variables that are not inherited from Windows:

- BDS
- BDSBIN
- BDSCOMMONDIR
- BDSINCLUDE
- BDSLIB
- BDSPORJECTSDIR
- etc.

They were apparently introduced with Delphi 2005 and their numbers have grown since.

I could not find any place where they are stored, only references e.g. in the registry to $(BDSPORJECTSDIR). Apparently they can be overridden by the "user overrides" in the same dialog.

The online help just gives me an unhelpful error "Cannotfind file %s" (which is a rather embarrassing error), the docwiki at
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Environment_Variables
doesn't answer my question either, the only hint is "The BDS environment variable represents the installed location of RAD Studio."

Does Delphi store these variables anywhere? Or are they just generated from the IDE/compiler from e.g. the file name of the executable?

EDIT: Why did I not find the link to
[How are Delphi 'environment variables' such as $(BDS) evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870282/how-are-delphi-environment-variables-such-as-bds-evaluated)
? I certainly searched SO before posting this question.
Yes, that answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: Why would it store them anywhere if they can be generated on the fly?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it's not documented, so it could do either. That's why I'm asking. Maybe somebody knows?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - you were correct - my bad - didn't read carefully. Answer is gone, question is closed anyhow.