# How to retrieve the value of Environment Variables using OpenTools API?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.2-tokyo, toolsapi

I added some new environment variables in the IDE setup:

Tools > Options > Environment Options > Environment Variables > User Overrides

Those are just some paths like: `$(MYPROJ_ROOT)\Source`.

How can I retrieve one of them using the OpenTools API?

The IDE that I'm using is Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

Comment: You can use [`GetEnvironmentStrings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getenvironmentstrings?redirectedfrom=MSDN) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6870985/11480).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IOTAServices` interface offers a function `ExpandRootMacro` just for this purpose.